# How to use template string with prevState in react with useState() hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

In the following form input code I am using the property name as static value and it works:

```
       <input      
        name={inputName}
        type="text"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setValue((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            customerName: e.target.value,
          }))
        }
        style={{ fontFamily: "Jameel Noori Nastaleeq" }}
        readOnly={readOnly}
      />
```

While if I try to use it as a dynamic value that's passed to this component as a prop, it doesn't work how can I do that?

Dynamic value incorrect code:

```
      <input
        name={inputName}
        type="text"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setValue((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            ${`valueNameToUpdate`}: e.target.value,
          }))
        }
        style={{ fontFamily: "Jameel Noori Nastaleeq" }}
        readOnly={readOnly}
      />
```

Comment: Perhaps, you need something simple: `setValue((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }))`.

Comment: Okay that seems to make things even simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) - `[valueNameToUpdate]`. Example:

```
onChange={(e) =>
  setValue((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [valueNameToUpdate]: e.target.value,
  }))
}
```

This would also work with template strings. Example:

```
onChange={(e) =>
  setValue((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [`${valueNameToUpdate}-${e.target.name}`]: e.target.value,
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onChange={(e) =>
      setValue((prevState) => ({
       ...prevState,
       [valueNameToUpdate]: e.target.value,
      }))
}
```